# NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python, variables, global, nameerror

Updated Code Snippet:
I have updated to the 'self.' convention instead of global, but still having the only value returned the empty string assigned on the class level, but if this is removed, an error is thrown.

```
class MainDialog(QWidget, qcDbWidget4.Ui_qcQueryWidget):

    dbDir = ''
    DbSelection = ''
    dbPath = ''
    TabSelection = ''
    exportDir = ''
    exportFileName = ''  

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connect(self.dbDirSelect, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.getDirFileNames)
        self.connect(self.dbSelectButton, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.selectDb)
        self.connect(self.tabSelectButton, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.selectTab)
        self.connect(self.exportDirSelect, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.getExportDir)
        self.connect(self.exportButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.setExportName)
        self.connect(self.querySubmitButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.setQueryParams)
        self.connect(self.querySubmitButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.dbQuery)

    def getDirFileNames(self):
        self.dbDir = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self))
        self.dbDirDisplay.setText(self.dbDir)

        dbFileList = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.dbDir):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.db'):
                    dbFileList.append(file)

        self.dbSelection.addItems(dbFileList)
```

Comment: Which line is returning the error? What other answers have you looked at?

Comment: Don’t use `global`. You’re probably looking for `self.qcLevelCode`.

Comment: It appears to be coming from:queryStatement = "SELECT * FROM " + qcTabSelect + " WHERE " + qcLevelSelect toward the bottom

Comment: I've tried the self.qcLevelCode, but that returns the empty string I set as a placeholder and not the global reassignment in the qcLevelDbQuery method. NameError: name 'qcLevelCode' is not defined

Comment: That's because you need to change all references from `global x` to `self.x`, including in `qcLevelDbQuery`. Your code contains no global variables.

Comment: One of the benefits of using classes is that it allows you to avoid using mutable globals. So why on earth do almost all your method definitions contain the `global` directive? It looks like you have some confusion over the difference between class attributes and instance attributes, and the relationship between them.

Comment: When I remove the global variables, remove the class defined variables, and include the 'self.' I get AttributeError: 'MainDialog' object has no attribute 'dbPath' It does not store the variable value from the other method

Comment: I didn't think it should be necessary for these to be global, but it was the only thing I was able to make work with the other variables such as "dbPath"

Comment: For example, in the `getTabNames` method, once you remove the `global` statement the name  `dbPath` is just local to that method. If you want `dbPath` to be an instance attribute you need to refer to it everywhere in the class with the name `self.dbPath`.

Comment: BTW, you need to learn about [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Thank you. I finally realized what you were referring to in a more complete way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define variable on class level like

```
class A(object):
    c = ''
```

You can use 'c' as static class variable or instance variable (or both, but it's confusing). If you want to use it as static class variable you need to use it as `A.c` (static variable for whole class, accessible outside of instance methods). If you want to use it as instance variable you need to use  `self.c` (own variable for every instance). `c` as variable in this case will not be defined and if you will try to use `global c` you should have NameError.

Comment: I keep throwing an error that the variable is not defined if it is not defined initially at the class level then set to global for reassignment. How can I define the variable as instance, assign a value, then reference in another method within the same class?

Comment: self.qcLevelCode will be equal to defined value ('' in your case) unless you assign something to it somewhere. It could be done in `__init__` – constructor. In any method with statement like `self.qcLevelCode = "LCU"` or if you have instance assigned to some variable like `inst` `inst.qcLevelCode = "LCU"`.